# polynomial ring modulo: what are the residues?

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

I am working with the polynomial ring $K[X,Y]/(X^5,Y^4,XY^3)$. Is it correct that $[1],[X],[X^2],[X^3],[X^4],[Y],[Y^2],[Y^3],[XY],[XY^2],[XY^3]$ are the residues?
Thanks for your answers!

Edit: I am working with this ring as a vector space over $K$.
Edit 2:
$[1],[X],[X^2],[X^3],[X^4],[Y],[Y^2],[Y^3],[XY],[XY^2]$

Comment: Are you looking for a basis of your ring as a vector space over $K$?

Comment: @doetoe Yes, I will add that to my post

Comment: But $[XY^3]=0$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Oh yes, of course, I totally forgot about that! Are the other residues correct?

Comment: I think a basis is
$$\{[X^iY^j]\mid0\le i\le 4,0\le j\le2\}\cup\{[Y^3]\}.$$The dimension would then be $16,$ not $10.$

Comment: @AnneBauval But what about $[Y]$ and $[Y^2]$?

Comment: @hannah2002, those are included, as the cases of $i=0$ and $j=1,$ $i=0$ and $j=2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the elements of $K[X,Y]$ can be thought of as $K$-linear combinations of finite subsets of the set of formal monomials $\{X^iY^j:i\ge0,j\ge0\}.$ (Here, a $K$-linear combination of the empty set is thought of as the $0$ element, by default.) The set of formal monomials then comprises a basis.

To find a basis for $R:=K[X,Y]/\bigl(X^5,Y^4,XY^3\bigr),$ it suffices to determine which of the standard basis elements aren't in $I:=(X^5,Y^4,XY^3),$ which is the ideal generated by $X^5,Y^4,$ and $XY^3.$ The residues of these basis elements will provide a basis for $R.$ Clearly, since $X^5\in I$ and $Y^4\in I,$ then if $X^iY^j$ is such that $i\geq 5$ and/or $j\geq 4,$ we necessarily have $X^iY^j\in I$ by properties of ideals. That eliminates the *vast* majority of the standard basis elements right away, leaving only those with $0\leq i\leq 4$ and $0\leq j\leq 3$ as viable options. However, since $XY^3\in I,$ then for any $i\geq 1,$ we have $X^iY^3\in I$ by properties of ideals, which eliminates $4$ more of the remaining $20$ options that we had.

All that remains are $Y^3$ and those of the form $X^iY^j$ for $0\leq i\leq 4$ and $0\leq j\leq 2.$ The residues of these $16$ elements (most of which you already found) give us the basis we desire!